# Is it possible to set the current user name to a field of an item in sitecore cms?

Tags: sitecore

For example, my username in the sitecore admin is "Borj", whenever I create an article I want "Borj" to be automatically fill the author field of any article I would create.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible, but will require some customization.

By default you only have the following tokens: 
`$name`: Is replaced with the name of the created item
`$parentname`: Is replaced with the name of the parent to the created item
`$date`: Is replaced with the current date
`$time`: Is replaced with the current time
`$now`: Is replaced with current date and time
`$id`: Is replaced with the id of the created item
`$parentid`: Is replaced with the id of the parent to the created item.

[This post by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/01/Add-Custom-Standard-Values-Tokens-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) shows you exactly how to fill a field with the name of the user that's creating the item.

This is the code he uses:

```
public class MasterVariablesReplacer : SC.Data.MasterVariablesReplacer
  {
    public override string Replace(string text, SC.Data.Items.Item targetItem)
    {
      SC.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(text, "text");
      SC.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(targetItem, "targetItem");
      string result = this.ReplaceValues(
        text,
        () => targetItem.Name,
        () => targetItem.ID.ToString(),
        () => SC.Data.Items.ItemUtil.GetParentName(targetItem),
        () => targetItem.ParentID.ToString());
      return result;
    }

    private string ReplaceValues(
      string text,
      Func<string> defaultName,
      Func<string> defaultId,
      Func<string> defaultParentName,
      Func<string> defaultParentId)
    {
      if ((text.Length != 0) && (text.IndexOf('$') >= 0))
      {
        SC.Text.ReplacerContext context = this.GetContext();

        if (context != null)
        {
          foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in context.Values)
          {
            text = text.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
          }
        }

        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$name", defaultName, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$id", defaultId, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentid", defaultParentId, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentname", defaultParentName, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$date", () => SC.DateUtil.IsoNowDate, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$time", () => SC.DateUtil.IsoNowTime, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$now", () => SC.DateUtil.IsoNow, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$user", () => SC.Context.User.LocalName, context);
      }

      return text;
    }

    private string ReplaceWithDefault(
      string text, 
      string variable, 
      Func<string> defaultValue, 
      SC.Text.ReplacerContext context)
    {
      if ((context != null) && context.Values.ContainsKey(variable))
      {
        return text;
      }

      if (text.IndexOf(variable, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) < 0)
      {
        return text;
      }

      return text.Replace(variable, defaultValue());
    }
  }
```

If you then change the setting `MasterVariablesReplacer` to your own assembly and class, it'll also pick up on `$user`

In [this post](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/custom-tokens-and-nvelocity-for-item-creation/) Alistair Deneys shows a different way of doing it as well.

**[edit]**
Please do note that the (untested) code provided above will not work with branches - just with the 'usual' way of creating items.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore already stores the user who created an item in the **__created** field if you just want to display the user name on the front end web site you could just use that field and strip off the domain i.e. **sitecore\**